# Class 'GetURLData' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(Params...)' in 'AsyncTask'?

Tags: class, private

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsFhX.png)

Hello, I have almost completed the weather app (first experience) While the skills are not enough to solve this problem," Class 'GetURLData' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(Params...)' in 'AsyncTask'" For whom it is not difficult, please tell me